# JSDoc inline object typedef

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdoc

Is there a way to write a typedef of a complex object inline the object keys instead of all in one block? For instance per the JSDoc docs https://jsdoc.app/tags-property.html, can this:

```
/**
 * Config type definition
 * @typedef {Object} Config
 * @property {string} prop1
 * @property {string} [prop2]
 */
let Config = {
     prop1: 'value1',
     prop2: 'value2',
};
```

become this:

```
/**
 * Config type definition
 * @typedef {Object} Config
 */
let Config = {
     /** @property {string} prop1 */
     prop1: 'value1',
     /** @property {string} [prop2] */
     prop2: 'value2',
};
```

I've tried all kinds of combinations of tags such as @namespace, @typedef, @member, @memberof, etc, but I can't get the nice property table that you get when declaring it all in one JSDoc block by trying any combination of tags in the inline format.

Defining the typedef in one block is okay until you try to define a huge config object that spans hundreds of lines. Having to jump to the top of the file to find the property description of that key is very cumbersome.

Comment: Have you finally found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use `@type` in each of your properties instead of `@property`.

```js
/**
 * @name Config
 */
let Config = {
    /** @type {string} */
    prop1: 'value1',
    /** @type {?string} */
    prop2: 'value2',
};
```